# Two columns layout with first column wrap_content, second fill_parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to design UI to contain two columns.

First column should wrap contained label and second in the same row should fill whole space. Below some example:

http://temp.chrzanowski.info/so_layout.png

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `TableLayout` with `strechColumns = "1"`

It stretches the 2nd column occupying the remaining space.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following `TableLayout` would give you the desired output:

```
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1">
   <TableRow>
      <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Bla bla bla"
           android:singleLine="true" />            <!-- first column's view -->

      <EditText
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> <!-- second column's view -->
   </TableRow>

   ...

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you ! Works well. I've accepted @mussharapp answer because of pointing `strechColumns` - just for the further devs.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can do a LinearLayout like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="40">
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A very very very long text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:ellipsize="end">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="60">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="TextBox">
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

To adjust width of columns, modify the `layout_weight` of each LinearLayout containers. Lesser value means smaller width, and both weights must equal 100.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >



        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Label 1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Label Loooong2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Label 3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="TextBox"/>
            <EditText 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="TextBox"/>
            <EditText 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="TextBox"/>
        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```